# Does @storybook/nextjs support writing stories for a component that uses page router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook

## Context

Hi have a component that

- uses URL state to switch between steps of a flow (to get backwards navigation out of the box. Lets say steps are X, Y, success or error, then routes are foo/x, foo/y, foo success, foo/error. There is also protection in place to force users to not go to a route directly if certain state set within foo/x is not set
- previously used react-router for that
- is showcases in Storybook

With the react router plugin for Storybook (https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-react-router-v6), that was doable. I could have the complete feature in Storybook, just by setting the initial router state as well as [msw handlers](https://storybook.js.org/addons/msw-storybook-addon) to mock api calls.

Now that we migrated to Next.js (still on page router), that component is now (sadly) tied to Next as Framework. I see that [@storybook/nextjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/nextjs) is the [recommended](https://storybook.js.org/blog/integrate-nextjs-and-storybook-automatically/) way of using Next features as the router in Storybook.

I understand that

- we see methods on the stubbed Next router called in the Storybook actions panel, so we can at least showcase that events like push happen
- it's [recommended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/nextjs#stories-for-pagescomponents-which-fetch-data) to not showcase whole pages but rather extracted components
- one can set router context properties using story paramets

```
export const Example = {
  parameters: {
    nextjs: {
      router: {
        basePath: '/profile',
      },
    }
  },
};
```

## Problem

Looking at the docs of @storybook/nextjs, I fail to understand if I can

1. only mock router state "statically", to bring a component using the router into a certain state by setting router props and listining for method calls
2. (which is what I want) use it to showcase components **full user flows** for components that use routing to manage their state

## Research done

I fail to find examples for such cases. Most examples show that one can showcase something like a Link and inspect that `push` on the router is called, which does not help.